# Memoization of method working on python 3.6 but not on 3.7.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.7

I use a decorator to extend memoization via lru_cache to methods of objects which aren't themselves hashable (following [stackoverflow.com/questions/33672412/python-functools-lru-cache-with-class-methods-release-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33672412/python-functools-lru-cache-with-class-methods-release-object)). **This memoization works fine with python 3.6 but shows unexpected behavior on python 3.7.**

*Observed behavior:*
If the memoized method is called with keyword arguments, memoization works fine on both the python versions. If it's called without keyword arg syntax, it works on 3.6 but not on 3.7.

==> What could cause the different behavior?

The code sample below shows a minimal example which reproduces the behavior.

`test_memoization_kwarg_call` passes for both python 3.6 and 3.7.
`test_memoization_arg_call` passes for python 3.6 but fails for 3.7.

```py
import random
import weakref
from functools import lru_cache


def memoize_method(func):
    # From stackoverflow.com/questions/33672412/python-functools-lru-cache-with-class-methods-release-object
    def wrapped_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self_weak = weakref.ref(self)

        @lru_cache()
        def cached_method(*args_, **kwargs_):
            return func(self_weak(), *args_, **kwargs_)

        setattr(self, func.__name__, cached_method)
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
        return cached_method(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped_func


class MyClass:
    @memoize_method
    def randint(self, param):
        return random.randint(0, int(1E9))


def test_memoization_kwarg_call():
    obj = MyClass()
    assert obj.randint(param=1) == obj.randint(param=1)
    assert obj.randint(1) == obj.randint(1)


def test_memoization_arg_call():
    obj = MyClass()
    assert obj.randint(1) == obj.randint(1)
```

Note that, weirdly, the line `assert obj.randint(1) == obj.randint(1)` does not lead to a test failure in `test_memoization_kwarg_call` when used in python 3.6 but fails for python 3.7 inside `test_memoization_arg_call`.

Python versions: 3.6.8 and 3.7.3, respectively.

#### Further info

user2357112 suggested to inspect `import dis; dis.dis(test_memoization_arg_call)`. 
On python 3.6 this gives

```
 36           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (MyClass)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 STORE_FAST               0 (obj)

 37           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (obj)
              8 LOAD_ATTR                1 (randint)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             14 LOAD_FAST                0 (obj)
             16 LOAD_ATTR                1 (randint)
             18 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             20 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             22 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             24 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        30
             26 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (AssertionError)
             28 RAISE_VARARGS            1
        >>   30 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE
```

On python 3.7 this gives

```
 36           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (MyClass)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 STORE_FAST               0 (obj)

 37           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (obj)
              8 LOAD_METHOD              1 (randint)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             12 CALL_METHOD              1
             14 LOAD_FAST                0 (obj)
             16 LOAD_METHOD              1 (randint)
             18 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             20 CALL_METHOD              1
             22 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             24 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        30
             26 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (AssertionError)
             28 RAISE_VARARGS            1
        >>   30 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE
```

the difference being that on 3.6 the call to the cached `randint` method yields `LOAD_ATTR, LOAD_CONST, CALL_FUNCTION` while on 3.7 it is yields `LOAD_METHOD, LOAD_CONST, CALL_METHOD`. This may explain the difference in behavior but I do not understand the internals of CPython (?) to understand it. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show the output of `import dis; dis.dis(test_memoization_arg_call)` on Python 3? Also, how are you running this code?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you describe on Python 3.7.0.

Comment: I too found both cases to work on both 3.6.4 and 3.7.2.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for suggesting `dis.dis`. I added the output above. on 3.6 the call to the cached randint method yields LOAD_ATTR, LOAD_CONST, CALL_FUNCTION while on 3.7 it is yields LOAD_METHOD, LOAD_CONST, CALL_METHOD. This may explain the difference in behavior but I do not understand the internals of CPython (?) to understand it. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2357112 I can reproduce the reported behavior both by importing and calling the function `test_memoization_arg_call` in a Python console as well as by running pytest on it

Comment: mine works on 3.7.1 - weird that a minor version would have a breaking change. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/changelog.html

Comment: This is a bug that has been fixed, and should be released as part of the next release. Raymond Hettinger has a good write up of what's going on in the Python issue tracker: https://bugs.python.org/issue36650.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug specifically in the Python 3.7.3 minor release. It was not present in Python 3.7.2, and it should not be present in Python 3.7.4 or 3.8.0. It was filed as [Python issue 36650](https://bugs.python.org/issue36650).

At C level, calls with no keyword arguments and calls with an empty `**kwargs` dict are handled differently. Depending on details of how a function is implemented, the function may receive `NULL` for kwargs instead of an empty kwargs dict. The C accelerator for `functools.lru_cache` treated calls with `NULL` kwargs differently from calls with an empty kwargs dict, leading to the bug you see here.

With the method cache recipe you're using, the first call to a method will always pass an empty kwargs dict to the C-level LRU wrapper, whether or not any keyword arguments were used, because of the `return cached_method(*args, **kwargs)` in `wrapped_func`. Subsequent calls may pass a `NULL` kwargs dict, because they no longer go through `wrapped_func`. This is why you could not reproduce the bug with `test_memoization_kwarg_call`; the *first* call has to pass no keyword arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I have a simpler solution about the problem:

```
pip install methodtools
```

Then,

```py
import random
from methodtools import lru_cache


class MyClass:
    @lru_cache()
    def randint(self, param):
        return random.randint(0, int(1E9))


def test_memoization_kwarg_call():
    obj = MyClass()
    assert obj.randint(param=1) == obj.randint(param=1)
    assert obj.randint(1) == obj.randint(1)
```

I am sorry that this is not the answer for "why" but if you are also intrested in fixing the problem. This is tested with 3.7.3.

Comment: thanks @youknowone for the helpful suggestion. I did not know about methodtools

Comment: out of curiosity @youknowone: I saw that methodtools references [Ring](https://github.com/youknowone/ring/). Is there any difference in using `@methodtools.lru_cache()` vs `@ring.lru()`?

Comment: Roughly, `methodtools.lru_cache` is a shallow wrapper for `functools.lru_cache`. They are the same except for method support.
`ring.lru` is a little bit different. It has rich features like optional expire, delete, update and data coding e.g json. It also generates human readable consistent string keys. The difference comes from the design goal - because ring is designed to be used also with external backends like memcached.
If you are interested in ring, check this document: https://ring-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/why.html

Answer (score 1):

i've never said this about python before, but this honestly looks like a bug. i have no idea why it's happening, because all this stuff is in underlying C.

but here's what i'm seeing, attempting to peer into the black box:

i added some simple printing to your code:

```
def memoize_method(func):
    # From stackoverflow.com/questions/33672412/python-functools-lru-cache-with-class-methods-release-object
    def wrapped_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self_weak = weakref.ref(self)

        print('wrapping func')
        @lru_cache()
        def cached_method(*args_, **kwargs_):
            print('in cached_method', args_, kwargs_, id(cached_method))
            return func(self_weak(), *args_, **kwargs_)

        setattr(self, func.__name__, cached_method)
        return cached_method(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped_func
```

then i tested the function like this:

```
def test_memoization_arg_call():
    obj = MyClass()
    for _ in range(5):
        print(id(obj.randint), obj.randint(1), obj.randint.cache_info(), id(obj.randint))
    print()
    for _ in range(5):
        print(id(obj.randint), obj.randint(2), obj.randint.cache_info(), id(obj.randint))
```

here's the output:

```
==================================
wrapping func
in cached_method (1,) {} 4525448992
4521585800 668415661 CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=1, maxsize=128, currsize=1) 4525448992
in cached_method (1,) {} 4525448992
4525448992 920166498 CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=2, maxsize=128, currsize=2) 4525448992
4525448992 920166498 CacheInfo(hits=1, misses=2, maxsize=128, currsize=2) 4525448992
4525448992 920166498 CacheInfo(hits=2, misses=2, maxsize=128, currsize=2) 4525448992
4525448992 920166498 CacheInfo(hits=3, misses=2, maxsize=128, currsize=2) 4525448992

in cached_method (2,) {} 4525448992
4525448992 690871031 CacheInfo(hits=3, misses=3, maxsize=128, currsize=3) 4525448992
4525448992 690871031 CacheInfo(hits=4, misses=3, maxsize=128, currsize=3) 4525448992
4525448992 690871031 CacheInfo(hits=5, misses=3, maxsize=128, currsize=3) 4525448992
4525448992 690871031 CacheInfo(hits=6, misses=3, maxsize=128, currsize=3) 4525448992
4525448992 690871031 CacheInfo(hits=7, misses=3, maxsize=128, currsize=3) 4525448992
```

the interesting thing here is that it seems like it mis-caches the first positional args call. this doesn't happen with kwargs, and if you call a kwargs call first, it won't mis-cache that or any following pos args calls (which, for whatever reason, means your kwargs test is working). the important lines are this:

```
==================================
wrapping func
in cached_method (1,) {} 4525448992
4521585800 668415661 CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=1, maxsize=128, currsize=1) 4525448992
in cached_method (1,) {} 4525448992
4525448992 920166498 CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=2, maxsize=128, currsize=2) 4525448992
4525448992 920166498 CacheInfo(hits=1, misses=2, maxsize=128, currsize=2) 4525448992
```

you can see that i'm in function `cached_method` with id `4525448992` twice with the exact same args/kwargs, but it's not caching. it even shows the misses themselves in `CacheInfo` (first, the cache is empty. second, it can't find `(1,)` for some reason). that's all in C, so i don't know how to fix it...

i guess the best answer is to use another lru_cache method and wait for the devs to fix whatever's happening here.

edit: btw, great question.