# How can I set an attribute in a frozen dataclass custom __init__ method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to build a `@dataclass` that defines a schema but is not actually instantiated with the given members. (Basically, I'm hijacking the convenient `@dataclass` syntax for other purposes). This almost does what I want:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True, init=False)
class Tricky:
    thing1: int
    thing2: str

    def __init__(self, thing3):
        self.thing3 = thing3
```

But I get a `FrozenInstanceError` in the `__init__` method:

```
dataclasses.FrozenInstanceError: cannot assign to field 'thing3'
```

I need the `frozen=True` (for hashability). Is there some way I can set a custom attribute in `__init__` on a frozen `@dataclass`?

Comment: "(Basically, I'm hijacking the convenient @dataclass syntax for other purposes)" Um, just don't do that? Or just don't use frozen and implement your own `__hash__`, seeing as you aren't really using a dataclass...

Comment: from where does `self.thing3` came up?

Comment: What *are* you using the syntax for then? Because the `@dataclass` syntax is not even dataclass-specific, it is just using standard annotations and type hinting. What problem are you solving by using adopting dataclasses?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: or just use `unsafe_hash=True` instead of `frozen=True`.

Answer (score 27):

The problem is that [the default `__init__` implementation uses `object.__setattr__()` with frozen classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#frozen-instances) and by providing your own implementation, you have to use it too which would make your code pretty hacky:

```py
@dataclass(frozen=True, init=False)
class Tricky:
    thing1: int
    thing2: str

    def __init__(self, thing3):
        object.__setattr__(self, "thing3", thing3)
```

Unfortunately, python does not provide a way to use the default implementation so we can't simply do something like:

```py
@dataclass(frozen=True, init=False)
class Tricky:
    thing1: int
    thing2: str

    def __init__(self, thing3, **kwargs):
        self.__default_init__(DoSomething(thing3), **kwargs)
```

However, with we can implement that behavior quite easily:

```py
def dataclass_with_default_init(_cls=None, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrap(cls):
        # Save the current __init__ and remove it so dataclass will
        # create the default __init__.
        user_init = getattr(cls, "__init__")
        delattr(cls, "__init__")

        # let dataclass process our class.
        result = dataclass(cls, *args, **kwargs)

        # Restore the user's __init__ save the default init to __default_init__.
        setattr(result, "__default_init__", result.__init__)
        setattr(result, "__init__", user_init)

        # Just in case that dataclass will return a new instance,
        # (currently, does not happen), restore cls's __init__.
        if result is not cls:
            setattr(cls, "__init__", user_init)

        return result

    # Support both dataclass_with_default_init() and dataclass_with_default_init
    if _cls is None:
        return wrap
    else:
        return wrap(_cls)
```

and then

```py
@dataclass_with_default_init(frozen=True)
class DataClass:
    value: int

    def __init__(self, value: str):
        # error:
        # self.value = int(value)

        self.__default_init__(value=int(value))
```

*Update*: I opened [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue38444) bug and I hope to implement that by 3.9.

Comment: The linked issue was unfortunately closed as "won't fix".

Comment: Hi, why do you indicate your solution as 'pretty hacky'? (`object.__setattr__(self, "thing3", thing3)`) It works fine and is compact. Is calling 'object' a bad practise?

Answer (score 12):

> I need the `frozen=True` (for hashability).

There is no strict need to freeze a class just to be hashable. You can opt to just not mutate the attributes from anywhere in your code, and set `unsafe_hash=True` instead.

However, you should really declare `thing3` as a field, and *not use a custom `__init__`*:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Any

@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
class Tricky:
    thing1: int = field(init=False)
    thing2: str = field(init=False)
    thing3: Any

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.thing1 = 42
        self.thing2 = 'foo'
```

Here `thing1` and `thing2` have `init=False` set, so they are not passed to the `__init__` method. You then set them in a `__post_init__()` method.

Note that this now *requires* that you don't freeze the class, otherwise you can't set `thing1` and `thing2` either, not in a custom `__init__` and not in `__post_init__`.

Demo:

```
>>> Tricky('bar')
Tricky(thing1=42, thing2='foo', thing3='bar')
>>> hash(Tricky('bar'))
-3702476386127038381
```

If all you want is a schema definition, you don’t need dataclasses at all. You can get the class annotations from any class; either as [raw annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-annotation) or with [`typing.get_type_hints()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints).

Comment: The real purpose of `Tricky` is a data access object, where the members define the schema of a table in a database. I don't actually ever want to actually set `thing1` or `thing2`; they're here purely to define a schema. (As I say, clearly not the intent of the dataclass, but the syntax is nice.) Clients will define subclasses of `Tricky`, each of which might define different members, but all of which need a `thing3` as defined in the superclass. If possible I don't want my subclasses to have to use the `field()` notation as this clutters up my nice clean schema definitions.

Comment: Just don’t use dataclasses. The notation is not specific to the library.

Comment: If I don't use a dataclass, do you know what would be the equivalent of `__dataclass_fields__`? I.e., how can I get only the fields defined with the `name: type` syntax?

Comment: Just access the annotations: `__annotations__`. Or the type hints with `typing.get_type_hints()`

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simpler option - just add a static `make` function:

```py
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Tricky:
    thing1: str
    thing2: int
    thing3: bool

    @classmethod
    def make(cls, whatever: str, you: bool, want: float):
        return cls(whatever + "..", you * 4, want > 5)

x = Tricky.make("foo", false, 3)
```

Depending on what your `make` method does it may be a good idea to follow Rust's naming convention - `from_foo()`. E.g.

```py
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Coord:
    lat: float
    lon: float

    @classmethod
    def from_os_grid_reference(cls, x: int, y: int):
        return cls(...)

    @classmethod
    def from_gps_nema_string(cls, nema_string: str):
        return cls(...)
```

Comment: This answer is buggy.  Use `@classmethod` if you expect a `cls` parameter.

Comment: I would go one step further and make `make` or `from_..` methods into standalone functions (like `make_tricky` etc.) - it's easier to add type annotation (you don't have to enclose it in quotes), it's one indentation less, it's more independent of actual class implementation and it may have shorter name

Comment: Type annotations are muss less of an issue now (no quotes needed) with [Python 3.11 and the introduction of PEP 673](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#whatsnew311-pep673)

Answer (score 5):

Turns out that dataclasses doesn't provide the functionality you were looking for. [Attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/) however does:

```
from attr import attrs, attrib


@attrs(frozen=True)
class Name:
    name: str = attrib(converter=str.lower)
```

Same answer to similar question: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64695607/3737651

Answer (score 4):

What @Shmuel H. posted did not work for me, it still raised `FrozenInstanceError`.

This is what worked for me:

What I'm doing here is accepting a value into the init and checking if its compatible with the format that is defined in the `strptime` function, if it is I will assign it, if not I will print the exception

```py
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Birthday:
    value: InitVar[str]
    date: datetime = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self, value: str):
        try:
            self.__dict__['date'] = datetime.strptime(value, '%d/%m/%Y')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: This code threw an exception.  I removed the "value" parameter as in   `def __post_init__(self):` and also used "setattr" as in: `object.__setattr__(self, 'date', datetime.strptime(self.value, '%d/%m/%Y'))` and it seems to work.  Please check "magomar's" answer also in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59222092/how-to-use-the-post-init-method-in-dataclasses-in-python