# __pre_init__ functionalty in python?

Tags: python

I would like to make string comparison case insensitive.
For that, I would like to create an immutable class with just one string field.
In the constructor, I would like to call lower() before assigning the value to the field.

I would like to use as much as possible of standard classes like namedtuple or dataclass.
Using the `__post_init__` function (see e.g. [How to use the __post_init__ method in Dataclasses in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59222092/how-to-use-the-post-init-method-in-dataclasses-in-python)) feels like a hack.
It also makes me wonder is the field still frozen after I changed it in the `__post_init__` function.

However, I can't find a `__pre_init__` function.
Is there a better way?

Comment: " I would like to call lower() before assigning the value to the field" -- So, is something stopping you from doing that? If so, pls elaborate. If not, what else is the problem?

Comment: Why wouldn't a .lower() in your regular init not be sufficient? Just a hobbyist here, so perhaps i lack some SE knowledge...

Comment: A `pre_init` - a mthod that is called before `__init__` is `__new__`. Look here for more
https://spyhce.com/blog/understanding-new-and-init

Comment: __new__ is the initialization of the class, __init__ the initialization of the instance. The conversion to lower should happen for all instances.

Comment: For example, overwriting __init__ of a NamedTuple as
````
class Name(NamedTuple):
    name: str

    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        def canonical_representation() -> str:
            return name.lower()
        self.name: str = canonical_representation()
``` is not allowed:  
```
File "C:\Users\laarpjljvd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\typing.py", line 1775, in __new__
    raise AttributeError("Cannot overwrite NamedTuple attribute " + key)
```

Comment: I am looking for readable and minimal declarations: something like
```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Name:
    name: str = field.lower()
```
such that I don't have to write all good functions for repr, hash, equality, etc, etc, etc...

Comment: @PierrevandeLaar, I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I took a guess at it with the answer I've left. If that is not what you're after, can you please update your question to clarify? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Turns out that dataclasses doesn't provide the functionality I was looking for.
Attrs however does:

```
from attr import attrs, attrib


@attrs(frozen=True)
class Name:
    name: str = attrib(converter=str.lower)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Clarification:** If I'm interpreting the question correctly, you specifically want to work with a class annotated with the stdlib [`dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass). Specifically, for your case, you might have something like this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class HasStringField:
    some_string: str


instance = HasStringField("SOME_STRING")
instance.some_string  # value: "SOME_STRING"
```

My understanding is that you want to implement something such that the value in `instance.some_string` above is actually `"some_string"`.

---

**Answer:** There is no "built-in" way to do what you want, but there are two options that come to mind: using `object.__setattr__` in `__post_init__` or else using an alternative decorator that provides you with a way to create a custom constructor that still calls through to the constructor created by `dataclass`.

**Option 1: using `object.__setattr__` in `__post_init__`**

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class HasStringField:
    some_string: str

    def __post_init__(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, "some_string", self.some_string.lower())


inst = HasStringField("SOME_STRING")
inst.some_string  # value: "some_string"
```

**Option 2: custom decorator**

The `dataclass_with_default_init` decorator in [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57893902/how-can-i-set-an-attribute-in-a-frozen-dataclass-custom-init-method/58336722#58336722) provides one such decorator.

Using the `dataclass_with_default_init` decorator, you'd do:

```py
# Import / implement the decorator

@dataclass_with_default_init(frozen=True)
class HasStringField:
    some_string: str

    def __init__(self, some_string: str):
        self.__default_init__(some_string=some_string.lower())


instance = HasStringField("SOME_STRING")
instance.some_string  # value: "some_string"
```

...and everything else about this class would remain as if you had used the `dataclass` decorator instead.

Answer (score 0):

This should be one of the simplest ways, the field you mention is the internal  `data` (inherited from the `UserString` class):

```
from collections import UserString

class LowerStr(UserString):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value)
        self.data = self.data.lower()

s1 = LowerStr("ABC")
print("s1: {}".format(s1))
print("s1 class: {}".format(s1.__class__))
print("s1 class mro: {}".format(s1.__class__.mro()))
```

Output:

```
s1: abc
s1 class: <class '__main__.LowerStr'>
s1 class mro: [<class '__main__.LowerStr'>, <class 'collections.UserString'>, <class 'collections.abc.Sequence'>, <class 'collections.abc.Reversible'>, <class 'collections.abc.Collection'>, <class 'collections.abc.Sized'>, <class 'collections.abc.Iterable'>, <class 'collections.abc.Container'>, <class 'object'>]
```

This gives you all the methods from `str` and you can customize them at will.

If you prefer to subclass, so there is no internal `data` attribute:

```
class InsensitiveStr(str):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return super().__new__(cls, value.lower())
        else:
            raise ValueError

s1 = InsensitiveStr("ABC")
print(s1)
print(type(s1))
print(s1.__class__)
print(s1.__class__.__mro__)
```

Note the differences in mro.

Outputs

```
abc
<class '__main__.InsensitiveStr'>
<class '__main__.InsensitiveStr'>
(<class '__main__.InsensitiveStr'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Comment: This class is not immutable. One can change the value of the data field.

Comment: `s1` is like an immutable string. Apart from `s1.data` of course. You can as well sub-class with the same idea. See my edit.

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255655/how-to-subclass-str-in-python#7255782) for similar discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Note: **I still think the best approach is to use the `__post_init__` / `object.__set_attribute__` mentioned above or to use an external library like https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/)**

One pattern I have seen reading the python code for dataclasses itself is to use a function with the same name but in snake case to do these sorts of changes. e.g.:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class HasStringField:
  some_string: str


def has_string_field(some_string: str) -> HasStringField:
  return HasStringField(some_string.lower())
```

Then you always import and use `has_string_field()` rather than `HasStringField()`. (An example of this pattern is dataclasses `field` vs `Field`):

- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/07236d562e59c6650227be18fa6ffc66b18d4741/Lib/dataclasses.py#L346
- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/07236d562e59c6650227be18fa6ffc66b18d4741/Lib/dataclasses.py#L252

It has the drawback of being verbose and making the class invariant's bypassable.

Answer (score 0):

### Python's preinit method is [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) :

You can't set attributes on a frozen dataclass, so I use a namedtuple here.

```py
from collections import namedtuple

_WithString = namedtuple("WithString", ["stringattr"])


class WithString:
    def __new__(cls, input_string):
        return _WithString(input_string.lower())


string_1 = WithString("TEST")
string_2 = WithString("test")
print("instances:", string_1, string_2)
print("attributes:", string_1.stringattr, string_2.stringattr)
print("compare instances:", string_1 == string_2)
print("compare attributes:", string_1.stringattr == string_2.stringattr)
```

Output:

```
instances: WithString(stringattr='test') WithString(stringattr='test')
compare instances: True
```

### You can do this in `__init__` too:

Equivalent behavior but this time with a dataclass. You'll have to [bypass the frozen attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#frozen-instances):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class WithString:
    stringattr: str

    def __init__(self, input_string):
        object.__setattr__(self, "stringattr", input_string.lower())


string_1 = WithString("TEST")
string_2 = WithString("test")
print("instances:", string_1, string_2)
print("compare instances:", string_1 == string_2)
```

Output:

```
instances: WithString(stringattr='test') WithString(stringattr='test')
compare instances: True
```

### Or just override `str`

The resulting object behaves a lot like a string and can also be compared to strings.

```py
class CaseInsensitiveString(str):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            return self.lower() == other.lower()
        except AttributeError:
            return NotImplemented


string_1 = CaseInsensitiveString("TEST")
string_2 = CaseInsensitiveString("test")
actual_string = "Test"
print("instances:", string_1, string_2)
print("compare instances:", string_1 == string_2)
print("compare left:", string_1 == actual_string)
print("compare right:", actual_string == string_1)
```

Output:

```
instances: TEST test
compare instances: True
compare left: True
compare right: True
```