# Python WeakKeyDictionary for unhashable types

Tags: python

As raised in [cpython issue 88306](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/88306), python [WeakKeyDictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakKeyDictionary) fails for non hashable types. According to the discussion in the python issue above, this is an unnecessary restriction, using `id`s of the keys instead of `hash` would work just fine: In this special case `id`s are unique identifiers for the keys in the WeakKeyDictionary, because the keys are automatically removed when the original object is deleted. It is important to be aware that using ids instead of hashes is only feasible in this very special case.

We can tweak `weakref.WeakKeyDictionary` ([see gist](https://gist.github.com/ptrba/b198f0cf6c22047df77483e8aa28f408)) to achieve the desired behaviour. In summary, this implementation wraps the `weakref` keys as follows:

```py
class _IdKey:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self._id = id(key)

    def __hash__(self):
        return self._id

    def __eq__(self, other: typing_extensions.Self):
        return self._id == other._id

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<_IdKey(_id={self._id})>"


class _IdWeakRef(_IdKey):
    def __init__(self, key, remove: typing.Callable[[typing.Any], None]):
        super().__init__(key)
        # hold weak ref to avoid garbage collection of the remove callback
        self._ref = weakref.ref(key, lambda _: remove(self))

    def __call__(self):
        # used in weakref.WeakKeyDictionary.__copy__
        return self._ref()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<_IdKey(_id={self._id},{self._ref})>"

class WeakKeyIdDictionary(weakref.WeakKeyDictionary):
   """
   overrides all methods involving dictionary access key 
   """
   ... https://gist.github.com/barmettl/b198f0cf6c22047df77483e8aa28f408
```

However, this depends on the details of the implementation of `weakref.WeakKeyDictionary` (using python3.10 here) and is likely to break in future (or even past) versions of python. Of course, alternatively one can just rewrite an entirely new class.

It is also possible to implement a custom `__hash__` method for all classes, but this won't work when dealing with external code and will give unreliable hashes for use cases beyond `weakref.WeakKeyDictionary`. We can also monkey patch `__hash__`, but this is not possible in particular for built in classes and will have unintended effects in other parts of the code.

Thus the following question: How should one store non hashable items in a WeakKeyDictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way which does not rely on knowing the internals of `WeakKeyDictionary`:

```py
from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary, WeakValueDictionary

class Id:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self._id = id(key)
    def __hash__(self):
        return self._id
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._id == other._id

class WeakUnhashableKeyDictionary:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # TODO Do something to initialize given args and kwargs.
        self.keys = WeakValueDictionary()
        self.values = WeakKeyDictionary()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.values.__getitem__(Id(key))
    
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        _id = Id(key)
        # NOTE This works because key holds on _id iif key exists,
        # and _id holds on value iif _id exists. Transitivity. QED.
        # Because key is only stored as a value, it does not need to be hashable.
        self.keys.__setitem__(_id, key)
        self.values.__setitem__(_id, value)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.keys.__delitem__(Id(key))
        self.values.__delitem__(Id(key))
        
    # etc. other methods should be relatively simple to implement.
    # TODO Might require some locks or care in the ordering of operations to work threaded.
    # TODO Add clean error handling.
```

This is just a generalization of [my answer to a method caching problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77097026).

Comment: I think this can produce false positives from `__getitem__` if a new object is allocated with an old key's ID while the corresponding `Id` instance and `self.values` entry are still around. That can happen if something like the [iteration guard](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/weakref.py#L221), (implemented [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.5/Lib/_weakrefset.py#L11)) delays cleanup of the `self.keys` entry.

Comment: [Yup, got a false match in testing.](https://ideone.com/BJg7uq) Of course, this `WeakUnhashableKeyDictionary` class doesn't actually implement iteration, so I had to iterate over `d.keys.values()` manually to activate the iteration guard. Still, I think `Id` should probably hold a weak reference to the key and check `self.keyref() is other.keyref()` in `__eq__` to avoid false matches.

Comment: [With the extra validation added](https://ideone.com/G4iIri), I no longer get false matches.

Comment: I guess it's impossible to implement iteration on top of either of self.keys or self.values without triggering this iteration guard. If that's the case then yes we need this additional weakref to handle the case where entries are indirectly deleted while they are being iterated over. Are there any other situations were deletion is delayed?

Comment: You can try to cheat your way out by iterating over the keys of `self.values` but I fear circumventing the iteration guard is going to cause trouble eventually: https://ideone.com/8FURDf

Comment: And none of those solutions handle `dict`s since they cannot be weakref'd. I guess it's a non-problem since none of the standard implementations handle `dict`s anyway.

Comment: You can improve idiomacy of the `__iter__` implementation: https://ideone.com/18ZEd9

Comment: You can simplify the extra validation implementation (rely on the referential identity of weak refs): https://ideone.com/CcEt5f

Comment: This is a clean solution using encapsulation rather than inheritance.

Comment: Should we edit the answer to include the caveats or maybe promote the solution that is most likely to work in all cases?

Comment: @Xoe Do you want to upload it to PyPI? It looks useful.

Comment: @Xoe editing the answer with the newest version https://ideone.com/CcEt5f  and mentioning caveats in the comments would be appropriate.