# Python method cache as object dict like cached_property

Tags: python, caching, methods, python-decorators

What I want is cache decorator for a method that works like `functools.cached_property`. `cached_property` caches the value of a property by adding it to the object `__dict__`, not to some global dict. Therefore, the object need not be hashable, as the "cache" (it's only one value) is stored in the object itself.

Now I would like the same thing for a method. So, something like a mechanism that creates a cache dict for the method in the object and memoizes method calls there. I know there are
`functools.cache` and `functools.lru_cache`, but they require the class object to be hashable, as the method is just treated as a function with first argument `self`.

I have looked quite a bit, the best thing I could find is the [cached_method](https://github.com/martenlienen/cached_method) package, but it only has very little stars. So either nobody needs this, there is a more popular implementation which I just can't find or this is trivial to implement in a few lines of code.

Does anyone know other more popular implementations?

Comment: Does this help at all? [Python functools lru_cache with instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33672412/python-functools-lru-cache-with-instance-methods-release-object)

Comment: Is there an issue with adding a `__hash__` method to allow the use of lru_cache?

Comment: @JonSG ah yes thanks for the link, there is ample discussion of this problem in that thread and the accepted answer is sort of what I was looking for. I suppose the package I mentioned implements sth similar.

Comment: @GuyGangemi yes, exactly the issues described in the thread JonSG referenced.