# Clearing LRU cache on all object properties

Tags: python

So I'm using `@lru_cache` on my objects in different parts, and I'm just wondering how to flush the cache on all functions on an object where @lru_cache is used, something like:

```
for i in dir(self):
  if 'cache_clear' in dir(i):
    self.get_attr(i).cache_clear()
```

The problem is:

- I'm not sure if this is really a very elegant way to do it
- cache_clear doesn't actually appear when I do dir() on the function which it decorates

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you request an instance method from `self`, Python returns a bound method object that does not have the `cache_clear` method.

You need to avoid triggering instance method lookup:

```
for value in vars(self).values():
    attr = getattr(value, 'cache_clear', None)
    if callable(attr):
        attr()
```

Keep in mind that `@lru_cache` cache is shared among instances of the class, which means that calling `cache_clear` from within one instance will empty the cache for all instances ([possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14946506/2301450)).

Comment: Just on the last point, if I have separate objects, they share a cache? Surely the data won't get confused, as 'self' is passed every time?

Comment: @cjm2671 yes, the cache is shared. Calling `cache_clear` within one of the instances will clear it for all instances. There're solutions to this, though http://stackoverflow.com/a/14946506/2301450